# Normalize an Array to Standard Normal Distribution

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, normalization

I think this is a pretty simple question but I wasn't able to find an answer.

I have an array:

```
array([ 62519, 261500, 1004836, ... , 0, 0])
```

I would like to convert it to a normal distribution with a min of 0 and a max of 1.

Any suggestions? I was looking at sklearn.preprocess.normalize, but was unable to get it to work for me.

The purpose is that I am creating a scatterplot with numpy, and want to use this third variable to color each point. However, the colors have to be between 0 and 1, and because I have some weird outliers I figured a normal distribution would be a good start.

Let me know if this doesn't make any sense. Thanks & Cheers.

Comment: It doesn't make sense why the normal distribution means `a min of 0 and a max of 1.`

Comment: Oh i'm an idiot, i jus twanted to standardize it and can just do z = (x- mean)/std. sry

Comment: To convert to normal distribution, `(x - np.mean(x))/np.std(x)`

Comment: normal distribution doesn't have max and min values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh I'm an idiot, I just wanted to standardize it and can just do `z = (x- mean)/std`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using Standard Normal Distribution for normalization, please consider using frobenius/l2:

## Frobenius/2-norm:

### Using Numpy:

```
normalized_z = z / np.linalg.norm(z)
```

### Using pure math lib

```
normalized_z = z / math.sqrt(max(sum(z**2), 1e-12)) # L2: Matrix Norm
```

### Using Tensorflow

```
normalized_z = tf.nn.l2_normalize(z,0)
```

Comment: Why? Isn't that the same?